# how to remove stroke after adding it to a button

Tags: android, android-button

I am trying to add a border (stroke) to a button when it is pressed, and then remove the stroke when another button is pressed. The problem is the button stays the size of the button+stroke instead of going back to the original size (without the stroke)

My attempted code is shown below:

```
front.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
            shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
            shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(30f);
            shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            front.setBackgroundDrawable(shapeDrawable);

            return false;
        }
    });

    back.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
            shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.GRAY);
            shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(0f);
            shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            front.setBackgroundDrawable(shapeDrawable);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to solve this problem was to set the background color to the desired color rather than making the drawable null. For my code example above I put the following code to be able to revert the buttons back to gray:

```
front.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(30f);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        front.setBackgroundDrawable(shapeDrawable);
        back.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        return false;
    }
});

back.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.GRAY);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(0f);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        back.setBackgroundDrawable(shapeDrawable);
        front.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the background drawable of the other button to null. Also, notice you've got the mistake inside the second method - you have `front.setBackgroundDrawable(shapeDrawable);` instead of `back.setBackgroundDrawable(shapeDrawable);`. The working code for your use:

```
front.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(30f);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        front.setBackgroundDrawable(shapeDrawable);
        back.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

        return false;
    }
});

back.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.GRAY);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(0f);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        back.setBackgroundDrawable(shapeDrawable);
        front.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: setting the background drawable to null gets rid of the button completely and only leaves the text that is on the button. Is there a way to set the drawable to null but keep the fill color of the button?